# how do i install ImageMagick php library/extension on Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, fedora

How do I install ImageMagick library on Apache 2. I am using Php 5.2.6 and Fedora 8. My php_info has no mention of ImageMagick.

I have tried: yum install ImageMagick and restarted apache, which didn't work.

I also added extension=imagick.ext to my php.ini file and restarted apache, which didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had to configure this today and I found it difficult to find good instructions.  Here is a solution I have tested on the Basic 32-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2010.11.1 Beta (AMI Id: ami-76f0061f)

```
yes | yum install kernel-devel gcc gcc-c++
yes | yum install php-devel
yum install php-pear # This line installs pecl as well as pear
yum install ImageMagick-devel
pecl install imagick
Add extension-imagick.so to /etc/php.ini
service httpd restart
```

You will see it listed now in phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments on the installation guide:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

ImageMagick is not itself a PHP library, it is a set of image manipulation programs, like a command line Photoshop. To learn how to install the PHP library, go to the PHP documentation.